# uitableview scrolling scrolls whole table in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xcode4

In my application I am using custom cell with a label and 4 unbuttons in the same sequence. Now when there are more data in the table and i scroll the table,it does not allow me to scroll properly and I am able to scroll only unto 7th row. and when i scroll up,the whole table gets scrolled to down. I have set one navigation bar at the top. I tried to resize the table to small height,but still the problem exists. Any solution for the same?

**EDIT**

I am posting my source code for reference :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(appDelegate.isCompleted ==TRUE)
      return [appDelegate.CArray count];  
    if(appDelegate.isCompleted ==FALSE)
        return [appDelegate.PArray count];  
    else
        return 0;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CellForActivity *cell = (CellForActivity*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CellForActivity alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.btn1 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btn2 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btn3 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btn4 setTag:indexPath.row];

        [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(PressC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(PressU:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressV:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(customCellButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if(appDelegate.isCompleted==TRUE)
    {
        NSString *strVal = [[appDelegate.CompltedArray valueForKey:@"Subject"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.DescLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d)%@",indexPath.row+1,strVal];
    }
    else if(appDelegate.isCompleted==FALSE)
    {
        NSString *strVal = [[appDelegate.PendingArray valueForKey:@"Subject"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//@"Follow Me";
        cell.DescLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d)%@",indexPath.row+1,strVal];
    }
    return cell;
    return 0;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

I am having a UINavigation bar at the top of the table.

Comment: Please post the methods in your tableview datasource and delegate.

Comment: Please find the source code in updated question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having one progress view in my view and after deleting the same my whole problem got solved. And with the same solution,I am closing my question. Thank you.